# Set the aspect ratio of a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using Matplotlib, I want to draw six plots side-by-side. However, I want each plot to have an aspect ratio of 1.

If I run the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

for n in range(1, 6):
    fig.add_subplot(1, 6, n)
    plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 4])

plt.show()
```

Then it shows the six plots "squashed" along the x-axis. This occurs even though I have set the x-axis and the y-axis to be the same length.

How can I make all the plots have an aspect ratio of 1?

Comment: Hmm, you could set the `figaspect` so as to have control over the figure aspect ratio to start with.

Comment: Try this: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
for n in range(1, 6):
    a=fig.add_subplot(1, 6, n)
    a.set_aspect(1)
    plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 4])`

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke *please* don't put long pieces of code in comments. And for that matter, don't answer questions in comments. Make an answer.

Comment: Have you seen http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html ?  In particular, note the call to `axis('equal')`.

Comment: And http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html

Answer (score 5):

With 5 plots side by side, you must set the figure size to allow for enough space for your plots, and add a bit of padding between plots so the text labels of the axis of one subplot do not overlap the next plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))

for n in range(1, 6):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 5, n)
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 4])

plt.tight_layout(pad=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]